# What does the DOCKER_HOST variable do?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, daemon, docker, boot2docker

I'm new to Docker, using Boot2Docker on OSX. After booting it, this message is given:

```
To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375
```

Yet even without it, basic Docker commands (eg, `docker run hello-world`) work fine.

The install instructions aren't very informative:

```
Note: If you see a message in the terminal that looks something like this:
To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set: 
export  DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375
you can safely set the evironment variable as instructed.
```

Knowing that it's "safe" doesn't say why it's useful.

What I'm not clear on:

1. What is the docker "client"?
2. What is the docker "daemon"?
3. What is the docker "host"? (The Boot2Docker VM itself?)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it.

The **client** is the `docker` command installed into OS X.

The **host** is the Boot2Docker VM.

The **daemon** is a background service running inside Boot2Docker.

This variable tells the client how to connect to the daemon.

When starting Boot2Docker, the terminal window that pops up already has `DOCKER_HOST` set, so that's why `docker` commands work. However, to run Docker commands in other terminal windows, you need to set this variable *in those windows*.

Failing to set it gives a message like this:

```
$ docker run hello-world
2014/08/11 11:41:42 Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.13/containers/create: 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

One way to fix that would be to simply do this:

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375
```

But, as pointed out by others, it's better to do this:

```
$ $(boot2docker shellinit)
$ docker run hello-world
Hello from Docker. [...]
```

To spell out this possibly non-intuitive Bash command, running `boot2docker shellinit` returns a set of Bash commands that set environment variables:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Hence running `$(boot2docker shellinit)` generates those commands, *and then runs them*.

Comment: One of the most clear and elaborate explanations; thanks, I'll be linking this to docker-oblivious people! (yep, they still exist in 2023)

Answer (score 5):

Upon investigation, it's also worth noting that when you want to start using docker in a new terminal window, the correct command is:

```
$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

I had tested these commands:

```
>>  docker info
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.15/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
>>  boot2docker shellinit
Writing /Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem
Writing /Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/cert.pem
Writing /Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/key.pem
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
>> docker info
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.15/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

Notice that docker info returned that same error.  however.. when using `$(boot2docker shellinit)`...

```
>>  $(boot2docker init)
Writing /Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem
Writing /Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/cert.pem
Writing /Users/ddavison/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/key.pem
>>  docker info
Containers: 3
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It points to the docker host! I followed these steps:

```
$ boot2docker start

Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
..............................
Started.

To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375

$ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375

$ docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo 'Hello world'
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:14.04' locally
Pulling repository ubuntu
9cbaf023786c: Download complete 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
97fd97495e49: Download complete 
2dcbbf65536c: Download complete 
6a459d727ebb: Download complete 
8f321fc43180: Download complete 
03db2b23cf03: Download complete 
Hello world
```

See:
http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerizing/