# Setting DOCKER_HOST after Docker Toolbox/Mac install

Tags: macos, docker, docker-toolbox

Mac here. I installed Docker via [the Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) and all Docker commands yield the same error:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/tmp$docker info
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

myuser@mymachine:~/tmp$sudo docker info
Password:
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

Interestingly enough, however:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/tmp$docker -v
Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79
```

[Google results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234793/4009451) | [for this error](https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/issues/79) indicate that the Toolbox did not install correctly, and that one of (or all) of the following env vars need to be set:

- `DOCKER_HOST`; and/or
- `DOCKER_CERT_PATH`; and/or
- `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`

I have verified `DOCKER_HOST` is not set on my machine (neither `env` nor `echo $DOCKER_HOST` show it). So my concerns:

- What are these env vars and what do they do? What are their proper values?
- How do I permanently set them so that they persist machine restarts?

---

#### Update

Running the commands suggested by the one answer so far:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/tmp$docker-machine start default
Error: Host does not exist: default
myuser@mymachine:~/tmp$eval $(docker-machine env default)
Error: Host does not exist: default
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run:

```
$ docker-machine start default
$ eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

And try again.

Those environment variables point your local Docker client to the Docker engine running in the VM. The above commands will set them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Mouat (+1) - are you sure this won't hose my local Vagrant or Vagrant/Docker config? If you get a chance, please have a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bubenkoff/vagrant-docker-example/issues/5).  Essentially I installed Vagrant, then installed Docker, and the Docker toolbox install hosed my Vagrant/VirtualBox installation. I then deleted everything and tried again and am currently able to run the `Vagrantfile` in that project which runs Docker. I'm worried that when I issue the commands you specify above, I'll break something else. Thoughts?!? Thanks again!

Comment: No idea, sorry. It *shouldn't* break things. That doesn't mean it *won't* :)

Comment: Actually, I don't see how those commands could break anything further than installing Toolbox may have.

Comment: OK thanks for the vote of confidence @Adrian Mouat (+1 both)! However please see my update, running both of those commands produces `Error: Host does not exist: default` error messages...any ideas?!?

Comment: Hmm, that probably is a bug to do with virtualbox. You could run `docker-machine create -d virtualbox default`, but it sounds like something went wrong during the install and running create is probably more dangerous.

Comment: Thanks again @Adrian Mouat (+1) - so I tried your `create` command, and it worked. Then I ran the `eval $(...)` that you suggested above, and that worked. I then ran `docker info` and *that* worked! Can you just confirm that I won't have to do this for each Docker project, or each time I restart my machine? If so, I'll call this *done*! Thanks again!!!

Comment: You'll need to run the start command when you reboot and the eval command in each new terminal. I suppose you could add them to a login script if you want.The thing is Toolbox should have run the create command, so there's probably a bug somewhere.

Comment: Does any of this change because of the Docker on Mac being completed? This no longer requires docker machine right?

Comment: Right, Docker for Mac will take care of all this for you.